# Run many scripts with different commands from bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, python-3

I have 3 scripts and I want them to be listening to a bluetooth command. When the Raspberry receive a command from the bluetooth, one of the three scripts must run. For example if the Raspb recieve the command "0", the script "0" will run. Anyone could help me please to do this.

Comment: The Pi seems irrelevant to any answer to this question.  The question seems to be how to write software.

Comment: The scripts already done, just i want to run them on the Pi simultaneously.

Comment: Hello. Which part is giving you trouble? Listening for commands on the bluetooth interface; parsing the received commands; launching the relevant scripts? Be more specific and maybe share some details/code you've already tried. Also clarify why this is a *Raspberry Pi* problem and not a general linux, python or bluetooth problem: you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: I am not very sure this is a Raspberry Pi problem. I am working on my Raspberry to implement this. So I need to listen for commands on the bluetooth and then I must launch the relevant script. To be more specific , I am new to Raspberry environment Thats why i cannot be extremely specific in the way of asking. I apologize about that. So could you please help me implement this.

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by writing an [RFCOMM socket](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html) (server) and implementing all the options you want. Here's how to proceed:

Write a script implementing an RFCOMM socket, listenning for your commands.
see: [**Example 4-2. rfcomm-server.c**](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html). Read the example comments.If you use C programming for example, then you can use: [**system("bash -c Script0.sh")**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) ... but you can also read about [**popen**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) too.

Note: You can send your custom command by writing an RFCOMM client, see
[**Example 4-3. rfcomm-client.c**](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html)

If you prefer python programming, you can see for examples here: 
[**bluez-intro**](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html)

*pseudo code and schema:*

```
 ----------------------------
|      BT RFCOMM SERVER      |
| if recvbuffer == command:0 |
|             popen -------------> script0.sh
 -----------------------------
               ^
               |
           command:0
               |
     -----------------------
    |   BT RFCOMM CLIENT    |
    | sendbuffer(command:0) |
     -----------------------
```

From the python MIT example:
**Example 3-2. rfcomm-server.py** (with example for your question)

```
import bluetooth
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)    
print "received [%s]" % data

# HERE MODIFICATIONS FOR PERSONNAL SYSTEM COMMANDS (not tested,
written on the moment)

fileToExec = None
if str(data).startswith("command:0"):
  fileToExec = "/tmp/script0.sh"
elif str(data).startswith("command:1"):
  fileToExec = "/tmp/script1.sh"    

if fileToExec is not None:
   process = Popen("bash %s && echo success||echo error;" % fileToExec, Shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   out, error = process.communicate()
   # Please read about subprocess
   print(out, error)

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Comment: Excuse me I just saw the tag for python but I leave the answer as it is.