# How can I control a Raspberry Pi over Bluetooth with an Android Smartphone?

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, android, kali

I am looking for ways fo control a RPI with Kali Linux over Bluetooth.

I would like to be able to turn on the RPI and connect to it via Bluetooth without using a screen, a keyboard and a mouse.

I tried to automate the launch of the Bluetooth protocol at boot but I wasn't able to connect to it using the app called "BlueTerm".

What could I try to automate the process and connect to the RPI right after boot ?

Comment: You can take a look on my [answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98847/run-many-scripts-with-different-commands-from-bluetooth). You should also write a BT client for Android.

Comment: If you fiddle around with `bluetoothctl` et. al., you should be able to either come up with a script, or get the devices registered to each other so they will automagically connect.  I use bt keyboards with pi's running Raspbian (I think Kali is pretty much the same in this regard as it is Debian derived), once I walk them through bluetoothctl they continue to connect whenever needed.  I think the relationship is reversed with a phone (pi would be slave).